# Fidning multivariable limit

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I'm having trouble in finding multi-variable limit and hope that an example like this could get me started on my work
$$\lim \limits_{(x, y) \to (2,0)} \frac{1-cosy}{xy^2}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a limit in two variable but the indeterminate form that comes out is due to a one of them. Then we calculate:
$$\lim \limits_{(x, y) \to (2,0)} \frac{1-\cos y}{xy^2}=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{1-\cos y}{y^2}$$
But it is a well-known limit:
$$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{1-\cos(t)}{t^2} = \frac{1}{2} $$
Then
$$\lim \limits_{(x, y) \to (2,0)} \frac{1-\cos y}{xy^2}=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{1-\cos y}{y^2}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{4}$$

Comment: Would I do something similar like plugging in x or y and pulling it out of the limit to most other limits?

Comment: No, there is not a general rule. It depends on the limit.

Answer (score 0):

$1-\cos(y)=2 \sin^2 \left(\frac{y}{2}\right)$

Then use the equivalency of $\sin^2\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)\sim \frac{y^2}{4}$ when $y$ is close to $0$.

The answer is $\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: It would be beneficial to use TeX code going forward.  You will find a tutorial [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).